# How I get the value inside of a bullet point in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, bulletedlist

```
            <br />
            <input type='radio' name='delivery_stat' id='delivery' ></input>
            <label htmlFor="pending" >Pending delivery</label>
            <br />
            <input type='radio' name='delivery_stat' id='delivery' ></input>
            <label htmlFor="done" >Complete delivery</label>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WocmW.png)

There are two options. Either pending delivery or complete delivery. If user select pending delivery then how do I get that value in my code in react.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to define [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) for the selected value from the radio buttons

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState()
```

And then, you should have a click event to handle radio selection

```
//state will be updated according to your radio selection
const handleChange = (e) => {
   setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
}
```

Lastly, you should add `value='Pending delivery'` and `onChange={handleChange}` to radio elements

```
<input type='radio' name='delivery_stat' id='delivery' value='Pending delivery' onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Full possible change

```js
const App = () => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState()
    const handleChange = (e) => {
       setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
    }

    return (<div>
       <br />
            <input type='radio' name='delivery_stat' id='delivery_pending' value='Pending delivery' onChange={handleChange}/>
            <label htmlFor="pending" for='delivery_pending'>Pending delivery</label>
            <br />
            <input type='radio' name='delivery_stat' id='delivery_complete' value='Complete delivery' onChange={handleChange}/>
            <label htmlFor="done" for='delivery_complete'>Complete delivery</label>
            
            <div>
              {selectedValue}
            </div>
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to manually control the `<input>` element's `value` and `onChange` props.

First, create the state for the value using `useState` for a functional component or `this.setState` for a class component, or using a global state management library (generally overkill for a simple form).

Then, pass the state value along with a setter function to the element.

More info [in the docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), although it unfortunately still uses class components, it's good practice to figure out how class components are written functionally using hooks anyway.